# How to add a total column to a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM [DSPCONTENT01].[dbo].[zWMGWEEKARRIVAL]
WHERE
[ARRIVED DATE] = 'WEEKLY TOTAL' OR [ARRIVED DATE] = 'PRIOR WEEK' OR [ARRIVED DATE] = '12 WEEK AVERAGE'
```

which displays this:

[image]

Is there any way to either add another column or create another table from it where it adds the total across?

Example:

```
ARRIVED DATE     TOTAL

WEEKLY TOTAL     12000
PRIOR WEEK       13654
12 WEEK AVERAGE  10094
```

Comment: You didn't specify an RDBMS, but just add the columns up, similar to:  [Theall] + [TheallUC] + [171] + ... + [OSB] AS [TOTAL]

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `+` but be careful about `NULL`s:

```
SELECT [ARRIVED DATE],
       (coalesce(col1, 0) + coalesce(col2, 0) + coalesce(col3, 0), . . .
       ) as Total
FROM [DSPCONTENT01].[dbo].[zWMGWEEKARRIVAL]
WHERE [ARRIVED DATE] IN ('WEEKLY TOTAL', 'PRIOR WEEK', '12 WEEK AVERAGE');
```

I can't easily read your column names, but you should include the real names.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the sum as a column in the database you can add what is called a [computed column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188300.aspx). You basically just add a query as the column. You can do that from within SSMS in the table designer under Computed Column Specification or by an alter table statement as described in the link.

```
ALTER TABLE zWMGWEEKARRIVAL 
ADD Total AS (Theall + TheallUC + ....rest of columns )
```